# Powershell PSSession Not Working

Tags: powershell

Trying to test PSSession with powershell

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName <servername>
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <servername> -ScripBlock {
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | %{ write-host 'Checking drive ' $_.Root; set-location $_.Root; Get-ChildItem -Filter "load4.wav" -Recurse; write-host 'Checked drive ' $_.Root; } | Out-File "$env:UserProfile\Desktop\$env:ComputerName-Results.txt"
}
```

I would eventually like to be able to run this against a list of servers and save save the results locally if possible

So when I run it will enter the PSSession

```
[server]: PS C:\Users\US_Chris.Ondrovic\Documents>
```

But will not execute this part of the code

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server -ScripBlock {
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | %{ write-host 'Checking drive ' $_.Root; set-location $_.Root; Get-ChildItem -Filter "load4.wav" -Recurse; write-host 'Checked drive ' $_.Root; } | Out-File "$env:UserProfile\Desktop\$env:ComputerName-Results.txt"
}
```

So I can verify this works like it is supposed to on the remote machine

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <server> -ScriptBlock {Get-Service} | Out-File $env:Userprofile\Desktop\Test.txt
```

Got it some what working, now it runs on through the PSSession but isn't looking for what I need

```
function Remote-Search() {
param([string[]]$Servers, [string]$Item)

foreach($server in $Servers) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | %{ write-host 'Checking drive ' $_.Root; set-location $_.Root; Get-ChildItem -Filter $item -Recurse; write-host 'Checked drive ' $_.Root; }} | Out-File $env:Userprofile\Desktop\$server-results-$item.txt
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Not Working"? Do you get an error? There's also a spelling mistake in `ScripBlock`.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: No error message just not searching for the files I am specifying should be looking for *.wav but seems to be listing other files as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```powershell
function Remote-Search() {
    param([string[]]$Servers, [string]$Item)

    foreach($server in $Servers) {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ArgumentList $Item -ScriptBlock { param([string]$filter)
            Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | %{ 
                write-host 'Checking drive ' $_.Root
                set-location $_.Root
                Get-ChildItem -Filter $filter -Recurse
                write-host 'Checked drive ' $_.Root 
            }
        } | Out-File $env:Userprofile\Desktop\$server-results-$item.txt
    } 
}
```

Variables in your script aren't available directly to the script block. You can declare parameters in the script block and then pass values to them through the `-ArgumentList` parameter of `Invoke-Command`.

So here, I've added a `$filter` parameter to the script block, and I passed in `$Item` through the `-ArgumentList` parameter of `Invoke-Command`. Now in the script block, on the remote machine, `$filter` will have that value.

Comment: I left out a ')' in the param declaration (now fixed), though you should have seen an error about that. I just rant this against 2 servers, and I got the expected results (a file on the desktop for each server with the filtered output of `Get-ChildItem`).

Answer (score 0):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server -ScripBlock {
    Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | %{ write-host 'Checking drive ' $_.Root; set-location $_.Root; Get-ChildItem -Filter "load4.wav" -Recurse; write-host 'Checked drive ' $_.Root; } | Out-File "$env:UserProfile\Desktop\$env:ComputerName-Results.txt"
}
```

Assuming this was copied verbatim, you are missing a "t" in `-ScriptBlock`